# Kafka MirrorMaker2 not replicating Kafka internal topics starting with "__"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to use MirrorMaker 2 to replicate the Kafka topics, but it doesn't replicate the topics starting with "__" (Kafka internal topics). What configs should I need to add in my MM2 script to make it replicate everything?

I created a new topic with the name - `__test-internal-topic-mm2`, but the MM2 service didn't replicate the topic. Whereas it is replicating all other topics which are not starting with `"__"`

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker filters out topics with the `__` prefix by default. To change that you need to provide your own [`ReplicationPolicy`](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/ReplicationPolicy.html) implementation, that overrides the [`isInternalTopic()`](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/ReplicationPolicy.html#isInternalTopic(java.lang.String)) method. See the [line](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror-client/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/ReplicationPolicy.java#L87) in the default method that filters these topics.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to handle it with config itself? I want to avoid writing implementation and build jars and inject it.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this via configs. As I mentioned, this is hard coded in the existing ReplicationPolicy implementations included with Kafka. This is because it usually does not make sense to mirror internal topics as they contain data specific to a cluster instance.

Comment: @MickaelMaison - How to use the custom ReplicationPolicy implementation with mirror make 2?

Comment: No talking about internal topics. But when can some topic data get replicated and some don't via MM?